# Which version of JQuery is used by Bundle.cs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the ASP.Net 4.0 Bundling feature.  In my ~/Scripts folder, I have several versions of jquery-xxx and jquery-ui-yyy.  The xxx versions are 
1.4.4, 
1.6.4, 
1.8.3, 
1.9.1.

The yyy versions are 
1.8.1, 
1.8.custom, 
1.9.2, 
1.10.0.

Which ones are in effect in the following bundles table?  Thanks.

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        #region JavaScript bundles
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{version}` will be replaced to pattern `(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3})` and all files that match that regex will be included.

Comment: Thank you. But which version of jquery is used at runtime?

Comment: In my opinion it will be some mix of all versions. You should avoid including multiple version of the same library.

Answer (score 1):

As Slawomir says, it will include all versions.

If you have

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foo").Include(
            "~/Scripts/foo-{version}.js"));
```

And the following files in /Scripts

```
foo-1.js
foo-2.1.js
foo-32-1.100.js
```

If you add the following to your view:

You end up with rendered (in debug mode) html of:

```
//note that foo-1.js does not match
<script src="/Scripts/foo-2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foo-32.1.100.js"></script>
```

This provides an easy way to upgrade you scripts without having to recompile, but again as Slawomwir says, you will end up with all files matching that `(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3})` regex